# Pandas. Фильтрация датафрейма

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-spreadsheet

Есть задача найти все данные по конкретной фамилии за определённый период времени (на картинке это "Головин Д.А." и период времени с 27.02 по 03.03
Я получил нужные данные, но код такой некрасивый и я понимаю, что сделал это очень грязно

Есть:

```
# Наш датафрейм из гугл таблицы
df = pd.read_csv(url)   
# Список колонок/даты по которым собираем данные – условно это наш календарь
date_to_find2 = ['27.02', '28.02', '01.03', '02.03', '03.03']
#Сотрудник, по которому нужно собрать данные
employee = 'Головин Д.А.'


#При конвертации из гугл таблицы в csv получаем много NaN
df = df.fillna('')


#Начинаю парсить данные
# ПЕРВОЕ: Начинаю отбирать те сроки, где не пустая хотя бы одна ячейка в календаре
df = df.loc[((df[date_to_find2[0]] != '') | (df[date_to_find2[1]] != '') | (df[date_to_find2[2]] != '') |
             (df[date_to_find2[3]] != '') | (df[date_to_find2[4]] != '')), date_to_find]
# ВТОРОЕ: Полученный fd отфильтровываю по ФИО
df = df.loc[df['Текущий исполнитель'] == employee, ]
```

#УСПЕХ!!! Но так тухло
Я вначале думал, что не буду заполнять пустоты (fillna) и в df.loc напишу что-то типа `df[date_to_find2].isna().sum()`. Но нет, ошибка

Может кто-то подскажет, как лучше отфильтровать данные?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
,Наименование,Текущий исполнитель,"Статус задачи
заполняет исполнитель","Дни/
/срок","Факт
ч.дни",Прогноз,Не покрываемые ФОТом трудозатраты,№ 1,08.09,09.09,10.09,11.09,12.09,№ 2,27.02,28.02,01.03,02.03,03.03,Задачи,Пометки/скрины 
ОБЪЕКТ,,СТАДИЯ,ЭТАП/КОРПУС,,СОГЛ. ЗАКАЗ.,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Все что написано в столбце ""задачи"" не удалять!!!(кроме руководителя)", 
,,,,,FALSE,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
ВЫДЕЛЕНО,ОБЩИЙ ПРОЦЕНТ ГОТОВНОСТИ,"Выделено/
План","Выделено/
Факт","Выдел./
Прогноз","Факт. дни до 23.06.2022
Данные от Решетова",История выделяемых трудозатрат,История убытка на листе,,,,,,,,,,,,,можно добавлять и менять текст на зачеркнутый, 
"76,61","25,25%","74,31","76,51","75,21",,"29.12.2022 - 34
04.02.2023 - 76.6",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
"Условно граф-е обознач-е статусов. При наведении курсора на УГО, появится комментарий с описанием.",1. - СТАТУСЫ СОТРУДНИКОВ,"Статусы с 1 по 5 заполняются исполнителями.
Статусы с 6 по 10 заполняются ведущими/руководителями",6. - СТАТУСЫ ДЛЯ РУКОВОДИТЕЛЕЙ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,2. Не в работе,,7. Запрос часов,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,3. В работе,,8. Отложено,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,4. Проблемы,,9. На согласовании,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,5. Проверить,,10. Завершено,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Столбик ""Статус задачи"" заполняет исполнитель", 
ТОМ,ЭОМ1 (Жилье) - заполнить в соответствии с составом РД,ГОТОВНОСТЬ ФАКТ. %,52%,"
2,3","
0,1","
1,4","
0",,,,,,,5️⃣1,,,1,,,, 
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
1,Формирование рабочих папок,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
2,Изучение исходных данных,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
3,Формирование перечня вопросов заказчику по проектируемой системе,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
4,Редактирование ТЗ,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
5,Редактирование ТЗ BIM,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
6,Формирование бренд листа,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
7,Определение состава проекта,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
8,Выдача заданий в АР на расстановку помещений,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
9,Выдача заданий в АР на расстановку ниш,Сарсенов А.У.,9. На согласовании,"0,25",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
10,Трассировка для инженерной концепции,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
11,Расчет нагрузок,Головин Д.А.,8. Отложено,1,,"1,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
11,Расчет нагрузок,Сарсенов А.У.,5. Проверить,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
12,Расчет освещенности,Сарсенов А.У.,9. На согласовании,"0,5",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
13,Расчет токов КЗ,,,"0,0625",,"0,06",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
14,Расчет сопротивления заземлителя,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
15,Расчет выбора КЛ,Головин Д.А.,10. Завершено,"0,125",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
16,Карта селективности,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
17,Укрупненная схема электроснабжения,,2. Не в работе,0,,"0,00",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
18,"Отправка схем, расчетов итд заказчику на согласование",Головин Д.А.,10. Завершено,"0,0625","0,06","0,06",,,,,,,,"5️⃣0,5",,,"0,5",,,, 
19,Составление ПЗ или ОД,,,"0,25",,"0,25",,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
20,"Формирование оформления - Обложка,титул,СРО",Головин Д.А.,10. Завершено,"0,0625","0,06","0,06",,,,,,,,"5️⃣0,5",,,"0,5",,,, 
ИТОГО,,,,"
2,3","
0,1","
1,4","
0",,,,,,,"5️⃣
0,1",,,,,,, 
"НАСТРОЙКИ
НЕ УДАЛЯТЬ СТРОКУ",РД,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, 
,настройки,,,,,,,,,настройки,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Можно увидеть данные в воспроизводимом (текстовом) виде?

Comment: Добавил данные. Чтобы не было та громоздко,  я удалил 5 недель календаря и несколько (200+) лишних строк

Comment: Посмотрите на результат такой конструкции: `df.loc[df['Текущий исполнитель'] == employee, date_to_find2]` для начала

Comment: Ну ок,  а как красиво отфильтровать пустые строки у сотрудника?

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой ответ

```
df[[any(x) for x in zip(*[~pd.isnull(df[col]) for col in df.columns])]]
```